# Should I buy a switch or a new router to make use of all the bandwidth I am paying for at home?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, bandwidth, wired-networking

This is my current network configuration, with the <- bandwith each device is receiving:

```
- ISP modem-router offering 300 Mbps both by ethernet or WiFi <- 300
    - TV (wired) <- 300
    - Router B (wired) <- 100
        - Desktop computer (wired) <- 100
        - Printer (wired) <- 100
        - Laptop computer (Wi-Fi) <- 100
```

The problem is that Router B is a 300 Mbps router over Wi-Fi but has only 10/100 ports, so it will only offer 100 Mbps both to the wired devices as well as to the laptop over Wi-Fi (because even if they can connect at 300 previously the router B is only receiving 100 Mbps).

Things as this, I see two possible solutions and I would like to know if they have some inconveniences that I don't see at this moment.

**Option A:** buy a Gigabit switch to use before my router B. I know that laptop will continue to be at 100 Mbps but this is not a problem for me. This would be the network:

```
- ISP modem-router offering 300 Mbps both by ethernet or WiFi <- 300
    - TV (wired) <- 300
    - Switch (wired) <- 300
        - Desktop computer (wired) <- 300
        - Printer (wired) <- 300
        - Router B (wired) <- 100
            - Laptop computer (Wi-Fi) <- 100
```

**Option B:** buy a router with Gigabit ports. Structure would be as the original but everything working at 300 Mbps (which is the bandwith I am paying for to the ISP, not the network's maximum capacity which is not the question).

**These are the questions that come to my mind:**

- Using only one router or a switch + router has an impact on the speed, or latency?
- Do all switches need to be plugged in to electricity?
- I am concerned about electricity usage. Apparently I would say that with option B I can have everything connected, I guess that a switch is more efficient than a router and I could turn off the router when I am not using the laptop which is most of the time.
- Having answered all this, any other reasons to go for option A or option B?

Clarification: I need to connect a laptop to a second device because the range of ISP's modem-router is not enough, maybe that wasn't clear. Apart of that, I don't need any other features apart from the switching capabilities and extending the Wi-Fi range.

Comment: Is there any other feature that you are using of Router B except for its switching capabilities?

Comment: No. Just the switching capabilities and also connect the laptop to Wi-Fi, the range of the modem-router is not enough to connect my laptop directly. So I need a switch and an access point, if I am not confused. But not any other network features (firewall, NAT, DHCP...).

Comment: “I am concerned about electricity usage.” You are massively overthinking all of this. Electrical usage is minimal at best for devices of this size. Just get what you want and stop thinking about what’s “best” and just get what is best for you and your desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Option A should, in theory, be faster since what you are referring to as a "router" is in fact a router+switch (and a whole bunch of other services).

Having two of such routers also usually means that you will have a double-NAT setup. This will not be beneficial towards speed/latency and it will further segregate your network. If you don't need this segregation or any of the other features provided by router B (e.g. a DHCP server), there is no reason to put a router in place.

Switches, in contrary to passive hubs, do need electricity to power the switching chips. However, you can power some switches using Power-over-Ethernet (PoE). So it does need power, but it does not necessarily be connected using a power cable.

Since you don't mention any specific services you need of router B except for its switching capabilities I suggest to replace the router with a gigabit switch. Another reason besides power usage and latency is the segregation of your network I mentioned before. If, at some point you want to allow e.g. traffic between TV and laptop you don't need to install any routes on the intermediary router since you have only one network. Then, there would also be no need for router B since you can connect it to the ISP router.

Comment: As you have sensed I am using router B just because of its switching capabilities, but also to extend the WiFi connection: my main router is far from the room in which I need to have Wi-Fi for the laptop. So, I thought that a router was the solution to a switch + access point. Now that I will put a switch, probably an access point would be enough but I guess that it's not worth buying an AP having already an old router I am using as Access Point. As the router is configured in bridge mode I understand that it is not acting really as a router and the network is one.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Given that it's already configured to work similarly to an AP there is probably no real benefit from replacing that with an AP.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Go for option A. That will be the simplest and most power efficient setup.

I would go for a single 8-port gigabit switch. This makes for a simplest setup and least complex to configure. Maybe even consider future proofing to a 2.5 gbit [switch](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/business-networking/unmanaged-switch/tl-sg108-m2/v1/) if your budget allows.

> Using only one router or a switch + router has an impact on the speed, or latency?

The less devices you use, the better your latency will be. But at this scale and speed you should not notice the extra latency. Rule of thumb is +0.3ms-1ms per consumer switch you add. Set your wifi-router to AP/bridge mode.

> Do all switches need to be plugged in to electricity?

Yes, switches are active components which require electricity.

> Apparently I would say that with option B I can have everything connected, I guess that a switch is more efficient than a router and I could turn off the router when I am not using the laptop which is most of the time.

Yes, the fewer devices you have running, the less electricity you use. And small switches will generally use less power than a router.

Comment: `I would go for a single 8-port gigabit switch.` Wouldn't that correspond to option *A*? Just asking because I'm asking myself if I misunderstood the original question.

Comment: I also think that the answer tried to say "option A". However, I need to connect a laptop to a second device, range of original device is not enough, maybe that wasn't clear. So if I use a switch I would also be keeping the router B after the switch, just to use it as an acess point for the laptop via Wi-Fi.

Comment: In that case I mean A. You can keep the wifi access point for wifi only and disable when you don't need it. This also allows you to  upgrade the wifi and switch separately. But why do you need a router B, doesn't your ISP modem also offer wifi?

Comment: Yes, my ISP modem also offers Wi-Fi but I use the laptop from a room which is far. The switch I am going to buy and the existing router B are connected by a wire that connects two separate rooms, so router B is placed more in the middle of my house while ISP's modem-router is in a corner.

Comment: If the wifi signal from the ISP router is not sufficient, which can could test with (www.speedtest.net), then I guess you must have both devices.

Answer (score 0):

Go for option A

- Wired networking can go through a stupid amount of devices before it affects performance and latency, for instance, if I run the tracert command in cmd. the 2 local routers my packets go through both send back latency readings of less than 1 ms. Unless there are some artificial changes to the network settings to slow down traffic then there should be practically no latency on a local **wired** network, no matter how many jumps there are
- a switch is a single digit wattage device, as the job it does it rather simple. if you have a computer, then the power requirements of a switch are negligible in comparison
- a switch requires power, on the wide majority of switches this is supplied by a power adapter, but if you are placing a switch somewhere where there is no power socket, then you could get a switch that's powered over an ethernet cable - POE (mind you this cable still needs to be powered somewhere off an adapter or a network device that provides POE - like a POE switch for example

Of course, option B is a valid choice too, and it might end up being a slighty more clean layout, but switches with gigabit speeds are very cheap. While a wifi router with gigabit ports will run you twice the cost.